# Fast Fourier Transforms on existing dataframe is showing unexpexted results

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, fft

I have a `.csv` file with voltage data, when I plot the data with time I can see that it is a sinusoidal wave with `60hz` frequency.

[image: Voltage data plot wrt time]

Now when I try to perform `fft` using the `scipy/numpy fft` modules, I get a spike at near `0` frequency while logically it should be at `60`. (shown below)

[image: FFT output]

When I tried it with a sin wave created in python I get proper results but I'm not getting it with my actual data.

I'm sharing my code below, please let me know if I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

```py
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq

df = pd.read_csv('Va_data.csv')

print(df.head())

N = df.shape[0]
frequency = np.linspace(0.0,100, int(N/2))
freq_data = fft(df['Va'])
y = (2/N)*np.abs(freq_data[0:np.int(N/2)])

plt.plot(frequency, y)
plt.title('Frequency Domain Signal')
plt.xlabel('Frequency in Hz')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

[Voltage data](https://pastebin.com/qeHew1uF)

Comment: can you please share the link to your `csv` file to make your problem reproducible? [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DrBwts The fft function returns an array, is my 'y' wrong?

Comment: @DrBwts I was told that the data is continuous and the sampling rate was 8000, so I just tried to write to write a script so it adds time starting from 1/8000 to 32 some thousand data points, this is how I plotted the time curve.

Comment: Data should be fine (although you didn't share a portion of it so we can't test it...) and FFT calculation (upto a constant) is fine too. It is about how you plot the results. To make the x-axis values represent the frequency information in terms of Hertz, you need `frequency = np.arange(N) / N * sampling_rate` and then you can crop the half of it `frequency = frequency[:N//2]` and give it to `plt.plot(frequency, y)`. What does this give?

Comment: ...remember that  each DFT coefficient `X(k)` for `k = 0, .., N-1` has a `exp(-j 2pi kn/N)` in it where `k/N` gives you the normalized frequency. Multiplying by sampling rate recovers the frequency corresponding to the continous domain.

Comment: @MustafaAydın The plot does not change in shape, but now my x-axis (frequency) went from being `0-100` to `0-4000` (sampling rate is 8000)

Comment: @siddheshk What location in x-axis now does the peak correspond to?

Comment: Is it around 60 Hz?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes, you are right, I am sorry for not paying attention I guess, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data should be fine and FFT calculation (upto a constant) is fine too. It is about how the the results are plotted. To make the x-axis values represent the frequency information in terms of Hertz, you need

```
frequency = np.arange(N) / N * sampling_rate
```

and then you can crop the half of it

```
frequency = frequency[:N//2]
```

and give it to `plt.plot(frequency, y)`. The equation for `frequency` above comes from the fact that each DFT coefficient `X(k)` for `k = 0, .., N-1` has a `exp(-j 2pi kn/N)` in it where `k/N` gives you the normalized frequency. Multiplying by sampling rate recovers the frequency corresponding to the continous domain.

A sample:

```
# sample x data
xs = np.linspace(0, 4, 1_000)

# sampling rate in this case
fs = 1 / np.diff(xs)[0]

# sine of it
ys = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 60 * xs)

# taking FFT
dft = np.fft.fft(ys)

# getting x-axis values to represent freq in Hz
N = len(xs)
x_as_freq = np.arange(N) / N * fs

# now plotting it
plt.plot(x_as_freq, np.abs(dft))
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.ylabel("DFT magnitude")

# to see that peak is indeed at 60Hz
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 250, 20))
```

which gives

[image: fft]